# RabbitMQ with mirrored queues: Failover support

Tags: rabbitmq, haproxy, pacemaker

I am trying to set up a RabbitMQ cluster with mirrored queues (nevermind if u don't know what that is, it MIGHT NOT affect the answer). Long story short, I have *N* RabbitMQ instances joined together in a cluster. One of the instances is the master, the remaining are slaves  - sorry about the terminology but thats what is on the RabbitMQ docs - but they are active. However, I need to come up with a proxying solution that does the following

1. Route ALL TCP connections to the master.
2. Should the master fail, reroute all TCP connections to a new master - one of the slaves will be promoted to master in that scenario.
3. No load balancing - all connections MUST go to the master (original or new).

Trouble is HAProxy seems to always work as a load balancer which is not applicable here, it is just here to provide failover support. How can I turn load balancing off but still keep failover support on?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/11/17/load-balancing-a-rabbitmq-cluster/) is a solution that tackles the exact problem that you describe.